# C Threads - Sync

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have this code, I am trying to create n threads, Do some work in each thread, and then reap each thread. If n thread is even, use detach, and if odd, use join,

When i run the program, it first prints out Successfully reaped thread, then doing working, then successfully reaped thread... looks like i have some synchronization issues

Do I even need to use Mutex?
Can anyone help me with getting everything running in the right order?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *dowork(){
    //Do whatever needs to be done in each thread here
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    long tid = (long) pthread_self();
    printf("Doing Work ...for %ld\n",tid);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    //pthread_exit(NULL);
    return;
}

void spawn(int n){
     if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    int i=0;
    //pthread_t * thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*n);
    pthread_t threads[n];
     while (i<n) {
        if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, dowork, NULL) != 0){
            printf ("Create pthread error!\n");
            exit (1);
        }
        i++;
    }//End of while

    // Wait for threads to complete //
    i = 0;
    while (i<n) 
    {
        int success = -1;

        if(i%2 == 0){
            success=pthread_detach(threads[i]);
        }
        else{
            success=pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
            }
        if(success==0)
            printf("Succesfully reaped thread\n");
        i++;
    }
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

}


int main() {
    spawn(5);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried running your code, but detaching a thread can happen while the thread is running - so your call to `pthread_detach` will return immediately, and thus your "Successfully reaped thread" will also most probably be displayed before the thread has a chance to print its "Doing work". `pthread_join` will wait for the thread to finish though.

Comment: you need `barrier` buddy.